# How to define variables outside the default loop in Macro Creator

Tags: automation, autohotkey, pulovers-macro-creator

In Pulover's Macro Creator, you can create [variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm). There are operator like `:=` and `+=` to set the values of the variables.

I want to do the following scenario:

- Create a variable with an initial value
- Send the value to an input box
- Increase the value of the variable
- Start the loop again

This is how the AHK code looks like:

```
var1 := 7
WinActivate, Input test ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Sleep, 333
Send, %var1%
var1 += 1
```

I guess, you all can see the problem.

*As every command is inside the main loop*, the variable always starts from the initial value. Unfortunately I can't define system variables, so I can't reach higher number than the initial value and the next number. If I skip the initial value, it starts from 0.

Can I somehow force the variable to be set only once?

Comment: Would you be fine with a pure AHK solution rather than a Pulover-utilizing solution

Comment: Yeah, should probably ditch that macro creator. I'm not saying it bad, I have never used it, but all I've heard about is jokes/memes. This problem seems also extremely easy if just done normally in AHK.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save it to an ini file? Write: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm  and Read: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm

Maybe:

```
global var1
; IniRead
IniRead, var1, MyScriptName.ini, My Var Section, var1-saved-key, 7
WinActivate, Input test ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Sleep, 333
Send, %var1%
var1 += 1
; IniWrite
IniWrite, %var1%, MyScriptName.ini, My Var Section, var1-saved-key
```

To start over, just erase the ini file.

Or write it right into the registry (very similar)?
Write: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegWrite.htm
Read: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegRead.htm

Hth,

Answer (score 0):

You could use Macro Creator's built-in variable **A_Index** which contains the number of the current loop iteration. Per PMC, "it contains 1 the first time the loop's body is executed. For the second time, it contains 2; and so on. If an inner loop is enclosed by an outer loop, the inner loop takes precedence."

So you could do somethine like below. *Note, there is no need to increment, as PMC does that for you through A_index.*

```
my_offset := 6
var1 := my_offset + A_index
WinActivate, Input test ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Sleep, 333
Send, %var1%
```